# is there any limit on the size for a data frame column? if my data is going more than 2gb it is throwing error 'out of memory"

Tags: arrays, json, pyspark, nested, azure-databricks

I wan to know whether there is any restriction on the size of the pyspark dataframe column

when i am reading a json file into the data frame using pyspark

df = spark.read.option('multiline', True).json('path')

display(df)

it is throwing the error and tasks are getting failed during execution

if I am reading the same file using

df = spark.read.option('multiline', True).text('path')

it is able to read the data.

my json contains a field which is holding the entire data of 2gb. this is field is nested array with 3 to 4 level arrays. any help is appreciated

Comment: it seems that it is a single json, so do your transformation, split json to several rows and show will work.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @ Lamanus transformation, split JSON into several rows.

And also try this **alternative approach** with **delta lake**. As per [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/delta/tune-file-size#autotune-file-size-based-on-table-size) delta lake has a high capacity to optimize the large datasets and it processing large JSON files in Azure Databricks.

**I reproduce the same thing in my environment and got this output.**

```
df = spark.read.option('multiline', True).json('dbfs:/FileStore/data__13_.json')

# write the dataFrame into a delta lake table
df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save("/mnt/delta/sampl1")

sd1 = spark.read.format("delta").load("/mnt/delta/sampl1")

display(sd1)
```

[image]